# R: How to calculate incidence of 2days duration from a cumulative data after extracting the maximum number of the same day?

Tags: r, dataframe, max, extract

I have a cumulative data like;

```
df1 <- data.frame(code=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5), 
                 date=c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03",
                        "2020-01-04","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-01",
                        "2020-01-02","2020-01-04","2020-01-03","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04"),
                 cumulative=c(2,3,3,4,4,4,4,6,6,7,8,10,13,14,16,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,5))
```

From here, I want to extract the maximum cumulative number of each code and each date like;

```
df2 <- data.frame(code=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5), 
                  date=c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03",
                         "2020-01-04","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-01",
                         "2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04"),
                  cumulative=c(3,3,4,4,4,4,6,6,8,13,14,16,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,5))
```

Now I have cumulative numbers for each code of each day. 
From here I want to calculate incidence of 2days duration.

```
df3 <- data.frame(code=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  incidence1=c(1,2,6,2,2),incidence2=c(1,2,3,3,3))
```

Incidence1 means the difference between 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-03,
Incidence2 means the difference between 2020-01-02 and 2020-01-04

What I want to know is 
1) How to extract the maximum number within the same day
2) How to calculate the difference between 2days

Please teach me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this by creating groups of every alternate row and get the difference of the `cumulative` value between them. To get the expected output in the same format as shown we can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  group_by(gr = rep(seq(1, n()/2), 2), add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(incidence = diff(cumulative)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = gr, values_from = incidence, names_prefix = "incidence")

#  code incidence1 incidence2
#  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     1          1          1
#2     2          2          2
#3     3          6          3
#4     4          2          3
#5     5          2          3
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. It seems this works with 4 days data, but I want to calculate much more dates. Do you know the way?

Comment: @tantan How would you calculate for more dates? Difference of 3-1 , 4-2 dates are calculated right now. What would be next combination?

Comment: My datasets has more than 1 month, so actually I want to calculate difference of 1-3, 2-4, 3-5, 4-6, etc... And also, do you know how to extract the maximum number (df1→df2)?

Comment: @tantan Can you try `df2 %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  group_by(gr = rep(seq(1, n()/2), 2), add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(incidence = list(diff(cumulative))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_wider(incidence)`

Comment: I think that "group_by(gr = rep(seq(1, n()/2), 2), add = TRUE)" will make the another meaning... I want to use the same date for twice (eg, 01-03 will be used twice for 1-3, 3-5)

Comment: Can you create an appropriate example which represents your data and show expected output for it?

Comment: Now I learnt to how to calculate the incidence thanks to Ronak. Do you know how to do df1→df2? Thanks

Comment: @tantan You can do `df1 %>%
  group_by(code, date) %>%
  summarise(cumulative = max(cumulative))`